# getServerSideProps always return null object as props

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

when I tried below code I get null object or undefined in console.

```
import React from 'react'
function Main({ data }) {
    console.log(data);
    return (
        <div></div>
    )
}
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const res = await fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=super&client_id=QqHDWLqMPbUQMFYXaMOjLF9iT81ceZzfXkMkiJF1hTQ`)
    const data = await res.json()
    return { props: { data } }
}
export default Main
```

Is there any error?
I also tried return something in Main function but still get undefined.

Comment: are you using `getServerSideProps` in next page or component?

Comment: I make Main.js in component folder and inside I use getServerSideProps

Comment: Components cannot use `getServerSideProps` only pages have such ability. If you move this to the `pages` folder, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)

> `getServerSideProps` can only be exported from a **page**. You can’t export it from non-page files.

You can't use `getServerSideProps` in a component. So make your `Main.js` to be a [pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages)

```js
// pages/main.js
function Main({ data }) {
  return <div>Main</div>
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const res = await fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=super&client_id=QqHDWLqMPbUQMFYXaMOjLF9iT81ceZzfXkMkiJF1hTQ`)
    const data = await res.json()
    return { props: { data } }
}
export default Main
```

> You should use `getServerSideProps` only if you need to pre-render a page whose data must be fetched at request time

Or keep `Main.js` as a component and [fetch data on client](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side) using `useEffect`

```js
function Main({ data }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    fetch('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=super&client_id=QqHDWLqMPbUQMFYXaMOjLF9iT81ceZzfXkMkiJF1hTQ')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data)
        setLoading(false)
      })
  }, [])

  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>
  if (!data) return <p>No profile data</p>

  return (
    <div>// rest of you code</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I move my Main.js file into pages folder and called Main.js into index.js but it still showing undefined. Is there any problem?

Comment: @Krunal Can say why ^^. I tried it works you can check it here [working exammple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-uxk3xk?file=pages/main.js)

Comment: @Krunal It's not enough to just move the file to `pages` folder, the component needs to be used as a page component too. In your case, move `getServerSideProps` to your `index.js` as that's the page component.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use your component in the page directory serversideprops not support outside

Comment: after doing this it will work

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses I resolve my code.